# CDI in ClientHeadersFactory failed after upgrade to Jakarta-EE 10 in OpenLiberty

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, open-liberty

i'm using Open Liberty 23.0.0.12 on OpenJDK 21.0.1+12-29 for my application. After upgrading the server.xml to use Jakarta EE Web Profile 10.0 instead of 9.1, injections in `ClientHeadersFactory` doesn't work anymore. In the following sample code, myBean is always `null`.

```
public class MyFactory implements ClientHeadersFactory {
  @Inject
  private MyBean myBean;

  @Override
  public MultivaluedMap<String, String> update(MultivaluedMap<String, String> incomingHeaders, MultivaluedMap<String, String> clientOutgoingHeaders) {
  }
}
```

The class MyBean

```
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {
}
```

The relevant maven dependency is jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-api:10.0.0.

I already nailed it down to something related to the upgrade to Jakarta EE 10 itself.
I upgraded the `beans.xml` and `web.xml` files to reflect the version change.
Injecting an interface instead of concrete class MyBean doesn't work either.
Maybe i missed some mandatory configurtion changes. But currently i'm out of ideas.

Update:

My `beans.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/beans_4_0.xsd"
       version="4.0"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Comment: You mentioned you're using beans.xml .   There were some changes in behavior in CDI 4.0 in EE 10, https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/cdi-beans.html#_cdi_scopes "Also in CDI 4.0 and later, a non-empty beans.xml file that does not specify the bean-discovery-mode attribute defaults this value to annotated. Therefore, by default, only objects with CDI bean-defining annotations are discovered as CDI beans. However, always properly specify a version for all beans.xml files, as shown in the previous example."   Can you paste your beans.xml ?

Comment: You can actually try to revert to the CDI 3 behavior with `cdi emptyBeansXmlCDI3Compatibility="true">` in server.xml.  I can add this as an answer if it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I added `the content of my `bean.xml` to the original question. Bean-discovery-mode is already set to all. Also adding `<server><cdi emptyBeansXmlCDI3Compatibility="true"/></server>` to the `server.xml of OpenLiberty didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only relevant change I can think of is that in EE 10, there was a behaviour change if you have an *empty* beans.xml. In EE 9 (CDI 3.0), an empty beans.xml is equivalent to `bean-discovery-mode=all` whereas in EE 10 (CDI 4.0) it is equivalent to `bean-discovery-mode=annotated`.

Based on the fact that you're not getting an error but `myBean` is `null`, I suspect that `MyFactory` is not being picked up as a CDI bean and therefore injection is not taking place.

Can you check:

1. In the archive which contains `MyFactory`, is there a beans.xml? If so, is it blank? If not, what value does it set for `bean-discovery-mode`?
2. Does adding `@Dependent` (or another bean defining annotation like `@ApplicationScoped`) to `MyFactory` fix the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
The `bean-discovery-mode` is set to `all` in the `bean.xml`.
Adding `@Dependent` to `MyFactory` doesn't change anything. More to that, i'm able to inject `MyBean`without any issues in other beans. For me it looks like, that injection just doesn't work in the context of `ClientHeadersFactory`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes if that's the case we should open a bug on Open Liberty and we'll get our rest client team to look at it. (I'm assuming this is the `ClientHeadersFactory` from MicroProfile Rest Client.)

Comment: Yes it is from MicroProfile Rest Client.
I just found [OpenLiberty Differences between MicroProfile 5.0 and 4.1](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/diff/mp-41-50-diff.html#_injection_for_the_context_annotation_is_not_provided_in_clientheadersfactory_instances) which mentions, that `@Context` is not provided anymore in `ClientHeadersFactory`, but nothing about `@Inject`.

I can open an issue at github.

Comment: I opened a bug at https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/27326